# Proof of the following convergence theorem

Tags: probability-theory

Prove the following convergence theorem. Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}) = ([0,1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]))$, $\mathrm{P}_m$ a sequence of probability measures, and $X_n \in \mathbb{L}^0(\mathscr{F})$. Assume

1. $\mathrm{P}_m(\lim _{n \to \infty}X_n = 0) = 1$ for all $m$
2. $X_n$ is uniformly continuous in $\omega \in [0,1]$, uniformly in $n$.

Show that $\lim _{n \to \infty}\sup _{m \geq 1}\mathrm{E}^{\mathrm{P}_m}[\mid X_n\mid] = 0$

For solving this problem it seems that I need to show $\mathrm{E}^{\mathrm{P}_m}[\mid X_n\mid]<a_n$ where $a_n$ is a sequence independent of $m$ and converges to zero. It seems that the second assumption should be useful to make $a_n$ independent of $m$ but I have no idea how to use that. Any help how to approach the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a positive $\varepsilon$. It is possible to find an integer $N$ 
such that if $|\omega -\omega'|\lt 1/N$, then $|X_n(\omega)-X_n(\omega')|\lt \varepsilon$ for each integer $n$ (this is a translation of assumption 2.). Define $I_j:=[j/N,(j+1)N]$ for $0\leqslant j\leqslant N-1$ and $J:=\{j\mid 0\leqslant j\leqslant N-1, \mathbb P_m(I_j)\neq 0\mbox{ for some }m  \} $ . For each $j\in J$, we pick $\omega_j\in I_j$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega_j)=0$. We then have 
$$\mathbb E^{\mathbb P_m}\left[|X_n|\right]=\sum_{j\in J}\int_{I_j}|X_n(\omega)|\mathrm d\mathbb P_m(\omega) \leqslant 
\sum_{j\in J}\int_{I_j}|X_n(\omega)-X_n(\omega_j)|\mathrm d\mathbb P_m(\omega) + \sum_{j\in J}|X_n(\omega_j)|\mathbb P_m(I_j).$$
Now, it suffices to collect all the information to reach the wanted conclusion.